# SUM of a field by DISTINCT rows

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to get a sum of a field 'count' on distinct row id.

Below is my query for it. How can we achieve this?

```
SELECT l.sid, l.Title, u.CompanyName, l.activation_date, l.expiration_date, COUNT(s.count), COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
            FROM listings l
            LEFT JOIN statistics s
            ON s.object_sid = l.sid
            LEFT JOIN users u
            ON u.sid = l.user_sid
            LEFT JOIN applications a
            ON a.listing_id = l.sid
            WHERE l.sid = 6276
            AND s.event = 'viewListing'
            GROUP BY l.sid
            LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Your question is confusing me. What are you trying to do? Also show your tables structures.

Comment: I want to be able to get a SUM() of a 'count' field making sure that the id of that count field is DISTINCT

Comment: This is for statistics table by the way

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sum of the column `statistics.count` by "listing" and by  "application", then you need to `GROUP BY` both "listing" and "application":

```
SELECT
    l.sid, l.Title, l.activation_date, l.expiration_date,
    u.CompanyName,
    SUM(s.count), COUNT(a.id) -- <= SUM(s.count)
FROM listings l
LEFT JOIN statistics s ON s.object_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.sid = l.user_sid
LEFT JOIN applications a ON a.listing_id = l.sid
WHERE l.sid = 6276
AND s.event = 'viewListing'
GROUP BY l.sid, a.sid -- <= GROUP BY clause modified
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this way I'm not getting correct application 'a' count. How can we solve this?

Comment: @Jae What is "correct"? Please provide an example (sample data, expected result).